# Can I make my Sims age again? What is a workaround for this bug?

Tags: the-sims-3

I seem to have a bug that is preventing my Sims from aging. It happened after my Sim had a baby. The "x days left until aging" bar never increases. Aging IS active in my game options.

I found [this thread on The Sims 3 that discusses the bug](http://forum.thesims3.com/jforum/posts/list/386308.page#5677628) but no one mentioned any solutions. Is there any way to get around this? I have every EP except Seasons and none of the Stuff Packs.

Comment: Did you double-check that aging is still on? I've seen reports of people having turned it on, then months later it turns off for some reason (possibly a patch glitch). They're sure it's on so they don't check again.

Comment: Yes I checked. Read the thread I linked, it's affected a lot of people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to throw a birthday party if I remember correctly.

Even in the post you quote it mentions

```
" I age them up with the TCE cheat. "
```

See more of the cheat from [here](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_The_Sims_3_cheats) (changed link to a better one, you would want the ageuptonpc cheat.)

Comment: Can I throw a birthday party if my Sim is not close to aging?

Comment: It's been a while, but I think once you get the x days left, then you can throw a party anytime in that timeframe

Comment: Yes, but my Sims aren't aging at all. As in, the day counter isn't moving.

Comment: Ah misunderstanding on my part, still using the TCE should still allow you to change this, if you are on PC

Comment: You [CAN](http://www.wikihow.com/Age-Faster-on-Sims-3) make any sim age by having them blow out the candles on a birthday cake. This can be used on the Xbox and PS3 as well unlike the TCE cheat since cheats aren't use-able on consoles.

Comment: That's interesting. Now I need to figure out a way to keep track of how old each Sim is.